# Can a father transfer rights to his daughter for gain?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting

In most western democracies a parent has obligations to the care of their children; they are not property in that their care cannot be transferred for personal gain, a child cannot be rented, sold, or abandoned. Whereas with property (such as a piece of bread) you can consume it, move it, sell it, break it, discard it etc.

In Judaism can a child be rented, sold, given away, abandoned (by their father)?

If no, why not? If yes, until what age or condition is met?

Comment: To reiterate the above, it's obviously not permitted to rape anyone (*'Arachin* 14b), much less have relations with a child (*Kiddushin* 41a, *Nidda* 13b), much less have relations with one's own child (*Sanhedrin* 76a).

Comment: As far as "slavery", you're referencing the biblical era practice discussed in Exodus 21:7-11. A destitute father would "sell" (more like a dowry) his minor daughter to be betrothed to someone (with her consent - Bach EH 37, Chelkas M'chokeik EH 37:10 and 56:6). In the interim, she'd perform the duties of a maid, and if neither the master nor his son formally commit to marriage by the time she reaches the age of majority (or after six years as a maid, whichever is first), she goes free.

Comment: Also, she can change her mind at the age of majority and decide to annul the marriage even though she previously agreed (this is called *mi'un*). Additionally, her relatives can redeem her monetarily from her status as a maid, and the master is legally required to be flexible with the amount they'd have to pay to redeem her. @AndrewRichmond

Comment: Thank you for this info, would be good to formulate into an answer.

Comment: @fred miun is only if her father died and her mother or brother married her off.  If the father marries her off, that's final unless they get divorced.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical of your claims. If my kid's daycare really likes them, they can't give me a competitive discount to keep my kid in their care? What do you mean by "their care can't be transferred for gain"? (I'm being picky with you because I don't think you really know what you're asking and that's why you have such trouble formulating it.)

Comment: @Heshy That's right about *mi'un*. Got a little mixed up; thanks for the correction. Nonetheless, she has to give initial consent, and it has to be when she is mentally mature enough to do so.

Comment: Upvoted in retaliation to downvotes, the question, as it appears now, is decent.

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe that the OP meant - can a man transfer the care for his children to third party, or must he do it by himself?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, you may sell your daughter into slavery.

> Now if a man sells his daughter as a maidservant, she shall not go free as the slaves go free. *[Exodus - Chapter 21](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9882/jewish/Chapter-21.htm)*

And a slave master may choose to beat their slave as long as they don’t knock out their teeth, eyes, or kill them.* He may then marry her or designate her to be married by his son or let her go free.

- *Jewish slaves may not be beaten. Rambam הלכות חובל ומזיק פרק ד הלכה
  יא,יג Note; most people are not jews*

Comment: -1 For omitting "if the girls is not married, she sets free" part, which makes the entire arrangement very different from common "slavery"

Comment: So much better yeah. (Sarcasm) People on here are slavery apologists, is that really your position - “Selling 8 year old girls into slavery is amazing, after years of forced labor and beatings they get to go free if their master thinks their unmarriagable!” I’ve updated the answer to include that the master can let her go free, I hope this satisfies your position.

Comment: It's a lesser evil, not a preferred practice, besides, you use manipulation here, "forced labor"? "beating??" Are you sure you read the rules for Jewish slave before asking the question? Being a maid and finally getting married (or released with sum of money when adult, see the rules for Jewish slave) is usually better then starve to death. It's unfair to condemn this rule from our rich, super-spoiled era. Fact is, that no one does it nowadays.

Comment: I’m not bashing the bible, I’m providing the correct answer to the question, if you find the bible offensive thats probably because it condones beating children. I personally see all people as equal, but if you think jews should be treated better than non jews, the bible agrees with you.

Comment: So your question is  - "Is the bible racist"? close this question, and ask another (and edit your answer, since beating is not allowed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98481/discussion-between-alaychem-and-andrew-richmond).

Comment: You aren't providing correct answers to anything. You are trolling with out of context misleading nonsense, as they say "a little knowledge is dangerous".  I'm sorry you got someone to bite, but the rest of us are just downvoting and moving on. Don't feed the trolls, and eventually they give up.

Comment: If my answer is incorrect, please provide a justification

Comment: It would be good to know that an 8 year old should not be sold into forced labor by their father, but it appears that is not the case. If you have evidence or justification for why this is not condoned in the bible or judaism then provide it.

Comment: I noticed you're implying that non-Jewish servants would be beaten. On the contrary, non-Jewish servants were to be treated well. The *Minchas Chinuch* (§ 338) rules that non-Jewish servants are in the category of "your people", and all the laws governing interpersonal interactions between Jews also apply to non-Jewish servants (e.g., don't make them feel bad, don't gossip about them, judge them favorably, don't hate them, don't take revenge against them or bear a grudge, love them as yourself, etc.)...

Comment: The Rambam says it is totally inappropriate to overwork servants or assign unnecessary work. He exhorts that proper behavior, in line with meta-halachic Torah values of compassion, egalitarianism, and justice, requires that masters treat servants gently, listen to their concerns and complaints, let them eat the same food and drink as the master eats (in fact, provide them with food before the master himself eats), not embarrass them, and not treat them brazenly or view them as having less intrinsic value than the master (*Hil. 'Avadim* 9:8)....

Comment: Rambam (Hil. 'Avadim 9:8), in explaining why a person should be respectful and attentive towards a servant's concerns (whether a Jewish or non-Jewish servant), cites Iyov 31:13,15: "Shall I despise the petition of my manservant or maidservant when they contend with me? ... Didn't the One who made me in the belly, make him, and fashion us in like womb?"

Comment: Regardless, by circumscribing the behavior of someone who owned slaves, the Torah does not mean that someone is encouraged to own slaves. Likewise, the Torah circumscribes the behavior of someone who had more than one wife, but the Torah is not specifically encouraging this behavior (the Talmud discourages polygamy - *P'sachim* 113a, and it was later forbidden by rabbinic fiat). A similar example is the law of the "beautiful captive bride" (*D'varim* 21:10-14) where the Torah does not encourage but rather tempers and delimits the behavior of soldiers on the battlefield.

Comment: The Torah gives a framework that can apply in all generations, including ones in the ancient world with different social norms when the total absence of slavery would have been unthinkable. Anyway, the English word "slave" has a lot of baggage and carries many negative connotations that don't apply to the institution of slavery in Torah law. E.g., the Ra'avan remarks (*Bava Kamma* 113b) that it is forbidden to kidnap anyone, Jew or non-Jew. Accordingly, it would be prohibited to have a slave who was kidnapped (although, in the Rambam's view, people abducted in war would be permitted as slaves)

Comment: In many instances, it would be forbidden to return even a non-Jewish fugitive slave to his master, and Jews are required to make full accommodation for fugitive slaves (*D'varim* 23:16-17, *Sifrei*, *Ki Seitzei* 259). If a slave's master struck him and gave him some permanent blemish (e.g., knocking out a tooth), the slave is immediately entitled to his freedom (*Sh'mos* 21:26-27) and to payment for damages inflicted by the master (*Hil 'Avadim* 5:14). This even applies if the master is a dentist and the slave tricks him into extracting a rotten tooth (*Hil. 'Avadim* 5:13).

Comment: As far as the specific case discussed in this answer, see the comments on your question above.

Comment: @Fred explain this then “a person who injures a canaanite servant whom he owns is not liable for any penalty” https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088911/jewish/Chovel-uMazzik-Chapter-Four.htm

Comment: Or how about this “if an owner knocks out one of his servants teeth (clearly a common mistake), and then blinds his eye, he must free him because of the tooth, but is not required to pay him because of the eye. (He can also be beaten by others without compensation since he hasn’t release papers) thank you bible for being able to beat my slave when they are no use to me, I can lash them then punch out his teeth, he is then free to get stabbed in the eye and have my colleagues beat him close to death. Maybe a good idea to remove his fingers and break his kneecaps.

Comment: @AndrewRichmond A person is not liable for damages in tort law for inflicting a temporary injury on the servant, but that doesn't make it acceptable behavior (notice also that the Rambam uses the word "patur", not "muttar"). There are many things prohibited in Jewish law vis-a-vis interpersonal interactions, but a person can only get monetary relief in a religious court for some of them.

Comment: @AndrewRichmond You are talking about an unusual case where the servant is in limbo as he has been freed but the process wasn't yet finalized. Because of a technicality, the freed servant can't get relief from the court, but if he takes unilateral action to seize the money for himself, he is entitled to keep it. Certainly, religious law doesn't permit you to beat someone just because you might find a way to avoid getting sued in court over it. Regardless, you are talking about a fringe case there.

Comment: It would be the case anytime a slave is freed because of the bureaucracy of getting release papers, who issues those? Have to go into town? Exception might maybe in modern times with electronic release of slaves, the slave owner could use an app on his smart phone to process the release.

Comment: @AndrewRichmond All he would need is for the master to give him a piece of paper/parchment/whatever indicating that he is free, certified by two witnesses or in the presence of two witnesses. A bit anachronistic to be talking about slavery and apps, though :/

Comment: So the slave relies on his sadistic master who knocked his teeth out to supply papers of his release? So he can then continue to beat the slave and specifically blind him before the master goes upstairs to write a letter of release. Hmmm... oh and the two colleague witnesses are then able to beat him too without repercussion just before signing the witness papers.

Comment: @AndrewRichmond There's a Talmudic dispute over whether he needs a document for his freedom to be finalized, and since this dispute is unsettled, the Rambam says he can't recover damages in court, but if he takes it for himself, the master can't recover the money back from him in court. Regardless, all opinions agree that he doesn't have to work for the master from the moment he is entitled to his freedom. See the above cited Minchas Chinuch; Jewish law requires kind treatment of servants, but now we're getting into a discussion of the technicalities of civil litigation in a fringe scenario.

Comment: I don’t at all think beating a slave would be a fringe case. Just looking at contemporary violence 25% of women will experience domestic abuse in their lifetime, which is in modern times where they can report it to police and be taken seriously. Here is a website with domestic violence statistics: https://www.domesticshelters.org/articles/faq/domestic-violence-statistics

Answer (score 3):

A man can't discard his young children, or starve them:

כתובות סה ב

> דרש רבי עולא רבה ... אע"פ שאמרו אין אדם זן את בניו
> ובנותיו כשהן קטנים אבל זן קטני קטנים עד כמה עד בן שש

Ktuvot 65b

Rabbi Ula Raba said... although they said the a man is not obligated to feed his young sons and daughters, he must feed his very young sons and daughters. How young? Until the age of six.

The condition of daughters from marriage is slightly better:

משנה כתובות ד יא

> בנן נוקבן דיהוין ליכי מנאי, יהויין יתבן בביתי ומתזנן מנכסי עד דיתנסבן
> לגוברין...

Mishna ktuvot p4 11

[One of the marriage conditions written in the *Ktuva* is:]

Daughters that you will have from me, will sit at my home, and will fed from my property until they we be married.

That's only until their puberty.

Also, a man must teach his son a profession:

קידושין כט א

> ת"ר והאב חייב בבנו ...וללמדו אומנות

Kidushin 29a

Our Rabbies said: Father obligation to his son... and teach him a profession.

About "transferring rights for gain" part:

A man can marry his young daughter to other, but I believe that the premise is that he is doing it for her own good (he can't support her, etc), doing it for gain is being *&^@%#.

A man can sell her for maid (Which is, again, for marriage. The master or his son must take her, or she is freed) only at the most dire situation:

רמב"ם עבדים 4:2

> אין האב רשאי למכור את בתו אלא אם כן העני, ולא נשאר לו כלום--לא קרקע,
> ולא מיטלטלין, ואפילו כסות שעליו; ואף על פי כן כופין את האב לפדותה אחר
> שמכרה

Rambam Laws of Slaves 4:2

"A father is not allowed to sell his daughter unless he became impoverished and had nothing, not land or chattel or even a shirt on his back, and even after selling her we force him to buy her back if he can."

Comment: But to directly answer the question, your saying yes a daughter is property which can be sold for money, am i missing something?

Comment: @Nephilim And a spouse is a long-term prostitute. You're missing any semblance of nuance or realism. The rest of us who aren't robots know the difference between a cow and a child, even with financial relationships between people and with inanimate objects being structurally parallel. A daughter is like property in that certain rights, privileges and obligations pertaining to your relationship with her can be transferred to others using, among other things, money.